# Angular expression in title tag in internet explorer 8 not working

Tags: internet-explorer-8, angularjs

I want to display a title rendered via angular. It works fine in browsers like chrome or firefox and also in internet 9 and 10.

The ng-app is defined in the html tag.

The title tag looks like this:

```
<title>    
{{resultListQuery.selectedPropertiesSummary}} in {{resultListQuery.geoCodingResult.locationName}}
</title>
```

Can anyone help me please? Do you need more informations about the app?

Comment: worst case could change title from controller => `angular.element('title').text( var1 +'in'+ var2)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$window.document.title` to set your title without binding.

Comment: this is unfortunate this answer has got a negative review, when it's actually the only one which is correct! {{...}} just fails (as well as ng-bind-template or ng-bind) in IE8 for updating the header, but $window.document.title works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
<title ng-bind-template="foo {{pageTitle}} bar"></title>
```

Alternatively you may also use `ng-bind`, but `ng-bind-template` has the additional advantage that it allows you to have multiple `{{}}` expressions within.

Comment: I've fixed a typo, could you please try again?

Comment: Uri is displayed in the tab instead of my title

Comment: I'd suggest that you open a new question on this, as discussion here gets a bit lengthy ...

Answer (score 1):

This is the cross browser solution. ng-bind and ng-bind-template would never work because they use element.text(), which never works with  on IE8.

```
myModule.run(function($interpolate, $window) {
   ...
   $rootScope.$watch(function() {
      return $interpolate(myTitleTemplate)($myScope);
   }, function(title) {
      $window.document.title = title;
   })
   ...
});
```